# How to draw box around specific text and setting of other text?

Tags: theorems

I am writing Question to Answers of my coursework. I have done it with some help but want to improve and beautify it further by controlling the spacing between question and answer working. The question counter works well.

```
\newcounter{ques}

\newcommand{\question}[2]{
    \noindent \fbox{{\parbox{7em}{\color{black}\textbf{Question \stepcounter{ques}\arabic{ques}:}}}}\hspace{.5em}
    \noindent \textit{#1}\vspace{.4em} \par       
    \noindent \textbf{Answer: } #2 \hspace{1em} 
    \normalsize \par \vspace{1em}}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I honestly have no idea what you really want. I guess you want to know a way of printing your question and answer stuff beautifully. I suggest the usage of `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newcounter{ques}
\colorlet{QuesCol}{green!35!black}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{myquestion}{Question}
  {colback=green!5,colframe=QuesCol,fonttitle=\bfseries,breakable}{qu}
\newcommand\question[3][\roman{ques}]{%
  \begin{myquestion}{#2}{#1}%
    \textbf{\textcolor{QuesCol}{Answer:}} #3%
  \end{myquestion}}

\begin{document}
\question[blind]{What happened to the blind duck?}{\blindduck}

See question \ref{qu:blind}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Its working well. However, found a little issue that answer box does not split to next page if it exceeds the limit of the page. You can check it with a large answer. Please guide How to control the large answer so that box moves on next page.

Comment: @itfeature.com see my edit. Use the `breakable` library and key.

Comment: There is an error message when I use enumerate environment when used in the question. For example, \question{Define: \begin{enumerate}\item Hypothesis \item level of significance \end{enumerate}}{|Definitions are...}. The Error message is "Argument of \XC@col@rlet has an extra }. }". Please help.

Comment: @itfeature.com you'll need another approach for stuff like that, please ask a new question. What does somehow work but doesn't give good looking results would be: `\newbox\foo\setbox\foo\vbox{\begin{enumerate}\item foo\item bar\end{enumerate}}\question{\usebox\foo}{foobar}`.